# Spring Boot: Prevent Jackson from "reformatting" XMLGregorianCalendar upon JSON serialization

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

My Spring boot application queries an external SOAP service. Having generated the classes from its WSDL/XSDs this is what a class looks like.

As you can see, the `dateOfBirth` is of type `XMLGregorianCalendar`. The SOAP response contains the date of birth in the following format: `1991-11-08+01:00`.

```java
public class Applicant {

    // other properties

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateOfBirth;

    // getters & setters
}
```

The Spring application receives the response body from the SOAP service and returns it "as is" to its calling client as JSON serialized by Jackson. The problem is, it seems as if Jackson serializes the `dateOfBirth` into another format.

This is the format the cilent finally receives:

```json
{
  "dateOfBirth": "1976-11-12T23:00:00.000+00:00"
}
```

Is there some configuration or custom implementation I could use so that Jackson won't reformat this date? In the worst case I could write a class which maps the SOAP response but this sounds quite tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring your mapper like so:

```
mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy+hh:mm"));
```

that should work
but if you want more control you can use @JsonFormat annotation:

```
public class Applicant {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    @JsonFormat( shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern ="dd-MM-yyyy+hh:mm")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateOfBirth;
}
```

for even more control : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

source : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs

Comment: The problem is, the `Applicant` class is generated from the external system's WSDL/XSD with `wsimport`, i.e. I have no control over the annotations in this class.

Comment: In that case just exposing an ObjectMapper with the DateFormat setted accordingly should do the trick but that configuration will apply to all the dates serialized as json in your application,  also if the wsdl is not expected to change and you'r not generating the sources in a deploy pipeline you can always add the annotations in the generated class (I know It's not THAT clean but it's a fast solution)